# Users and Followers on NestJS with TypeORM, how to implement?

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

Provided you have an Application built within the framework of **NestJS** with the use **TypeORM**.

Suppose you have **Users** that are able to follow other **Users**. The way I mapped this on my database is by using two tables like in the image (simplified data). Users table hold users data and Followers holds a pair of foreign keys, **they both are used as primary key for table Followers**. Its easy to see that a row on table Followers having user_id = 1 and follower_id = 2 means the later user follows the former.

Is this a good strategy? If not, why not and how to do it properly?
If yes, how to implement it?

The dificulty on implementing arises because I'm not sure how to implement the decorators on the entities. It feels like it should be a ManyToMany relation, though this will make TypeORM create an unecessary third table, when these two are perfectly fine. Also what about the two keys behaving together as a primary key?

[image: Diagram]

P.S.: Magon mentioned not using a relational database because this is graph orientad data. Tough he is right, I'll insist with the question since the objective of this project is improve my skills with NestJS and TypeORM. So try answering the question within the scope of relational databases.

Comment: No, this is a bad idea.

My suggestion will be to not use an RDMS for this requirement because you will have performance issues in the long here. You're trying to represent graph-oriented data in a relational database which is not right. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584598/how-to-persist-a-graph-data-structure-in-a-relational-database/20304574 for more details on why this is a bad idea & why you should use something like Neo4J or similar instead.

Comment: Relation should be OneToMany from Users to Followers. And in Users it is better to use  `user_id` field (not just `id`). About "two keys for primary key" - it's ok.